# my for loop is giving me more than 1 value

Tags: python-3.x

i have a nested for loop and each of my for loops are suppose to return one value,but the last for loop is returning 5 values from my list. How do i go about this.

```
ut = [[1,2,3,4,4,5,4,6,6,5,4,3,5], [2,4,6,7,3,4,6,7,4,3], [2,3,4,6,7,3,2,6,7,8,9,5],[2,5,7,4,3,6,7,3,2,5]]
t = [0,1,2,3] #length of ut
n = [12,9,11,9] #length of each list in ut 
for ic in t:
    for i in n:
        for j in n:
            print(j)
            ii = ut[ic][i] #for example ii = ut[0][12] = 5
            jj = ut[ic][j]
```

i get this error

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f5e2a3c2151d> in <module>
      6         for j in n:
      7             print(j)
----> 8             ii = ut[ic][i] #for example ii = ut[0][12] = 5
      9             jj = ut[ic][j]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The loop: `for i in n:`  is giving you indices like `12` that will fail when `ic == 1` since this part of `ut`: `[2,4,6,7,3,4,6,7,4,3],` does not have enough elements to call `ut[1][12]`

Comment: This seems like a very contrived example. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Why do you have `t`? You could just do `for whatever in ut:` as your first for expression.

Comment: What's the supposed output can you add that to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ic = 1 and i and j are equals to 12 you get an index out of range since the size of the nested array in ut is only 10

Comment: Good answer! I would suggest expanding on your phrase "since the size of the nested array in ut is only 10", you can write that much more explicitly like: "since the size of the nested array `ut[1]` is only 10".  Thanks for the answer and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when `ic = 1, i = 12, j=12`

At this moment, uou try to get the 12th element from the second sublist of ut (`[2,4,6,7,3,4,6,7,4,3]`) which is has a length of 10, which explains the exception...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your detail understanding..

```
for ic in t:
print(str(t)+"A=>"+str(ic))
for i in ut[ic]:
    print(str(ut[ic])+"B=>"+str(i))
    if len(ut[ic]) == n[ic]+1:
        for j in ut[ic]:
            print("C=>"+str(j))
    break
```

Here is My Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]A=>0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5]B=>1
C=>1
C=>2
C=>3
C=>4
C=>4
C=>5
C=>4
C=>6
C=>6
C=>5
C=>4
C=>3
C=>5
[0, 1, 2, 3]A=>1
[2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 3]B=>2
C=>2
C=>4
C=>6
C=>7
C=>3
C=>4
C=>6
C=>7
C=>4
C=>3
[0, 1, 2, 3]A=>2
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]B=>2
C=>2
C=>3
C=>4
C=>6
C=>7
C=>3
C=>2
C=>6
C=>7
C=>8
C=>9
C=>5
[0, 1, 2, 3]A=>3
[2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 5]B=>2
C=>2
C=>5
C=>7
C=>4
C=>3
C=>6
C=>7
C=>3
C=>2
C=>5
```